# Cell.Value property does not exist (although I used it successfully until a few days ago...)

Tags: excel, vba

I am totally novice in VBA.
I use Excel 16.27 (19071500) with VBA 7.1 (Office 365) on MacOS 10.14.5.

A few months ago, I created an Excel macro that I used successfully until a few days ago. Today, I wanted to use it but I got the following error on line 37:

```
Valeur = cell.Value
```

"Method or data member not found"

I already used this macro withut any problem for several months...

```
Sub Prepare_All_Data_From_Wac()
'
' Prepare_All_Data_From_Wac Macro
'
Dim Valeur As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim Nombres As Variant
Dim x As String, cell As Range
'

' Nettoyages de tous les [espaces] et de tous les [line break]

Range("B2:V2000").Select
Selection.Replace What:=Chr(10), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False


' Nettoyage de la colonne A (time-stamps)

ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A2000").Select
Selection.Replace What:="T", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False


' insertion de 1 colonne à gauche de chaque colonne de D à V (la derrnière colonne aura donc le numéro 40)

Range("D:D,E:E,F:F,G:G,H:H,I:I,J:J,K:K,L:L,M:M,N:N,O:O,P:P,Q:Q,R:R,S:S,T:T,U:U,V:V").Select
' Range("V1").Activate
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight


' Nettoyage de la colonne C et split sur es colonnes C et D (Dons, Donateurs UPR)

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C2000")
     Valeur = cell.Value
     Nombres = Split(Valeur, "€")
     For i = 0 To UBound(Nombres)
         cell.Offset(0, i).Value = Nombres(i)
     Next i
Next cell


' Split des colonnes D à V (devenues E,G,I,K,M,O,Q,S,U,W,Y,AA,AC,AE,AG,AI,AK,AM

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("E2:AM2000")
     Valeur = cell.Value
     Nombres = Split(Valeur, "abonnés")
     For i = 0 To UBound(Nombres)
         cell.Offset(0, i).Value = Nombres(i)
     Next i
Next cell


    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "02 Donateurs"
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "03 UPR V"
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "04 JLM V"
    Range("J1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "05 Ruffin V"
    Range("L1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "06 LeFil V"
    Range("N1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "07 Tatiana V"
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "08 7Mediapart V"
    Range("R1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "09 RTf V"
    Range("T1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "10 Sénat V"
    Range("V1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "11 SudR V"
    Range("X1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "12 ThinkerV V"
    Range("Z1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "13 LeMedia V"
    Range("AB1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "14 JSPC V"
    Range("AD1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "15 Osons V"
    Range("AF1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "16 Brut V"
    Range("AH1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "17 LFI V"
    Range("AJ1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "51 TVL V"
    Range("AL1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "52 RLEM V"
    Range("AN1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "53 RN V"
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

on line 37:

```
Valeur = cell.Value
```

Expected that the cell value to be copied into the Valeur variable

Actual result:

> Compile error:
>
> Method or data member not found

Comment: Let aside the use of unneccesary `.Select` or `.Activesheet` referencing. This error would occur, as far as I know, when collection wouldn't hold the specified member. In your case it would mean the specific cell wouldn't excist in your range. Are you sure the active sheet is correct? Can you use `Debug.print cell.Address` right in front of each `Valeur = cell.Value` and tell us what the last address is before you hit the error?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. In your old code you have defined **cell** as range.

and in this new code you may using it as vba keyword . Here you need to mention row and column in the cell.

Comment: Thank you to both of you for your comments. But I don't know how to go further on:

Comment: 1. When I put Debug.print cell.Address in the code (just before the line "Valeur = cell.Value"), I get the same error, but on cell.Address.

Comment: 2. How Can I retrieve the address of the active cell (cell.Address is not recognized)? Is there any other way? It seems I need to do something like this: For j = 2 To 2000 Valeur = cell(3, j).Value Nombres = Split(Valeur, "€") For i = 0 To UBound(Nombres) cell(3, j).Offset(0, i).Value = Nombres(i) Next i Next j Is this good?

Comment: 3. I also noticed that all the code before this “erroneous line” (line 37), that is supposed to have been executed without any error, was in fact not executed! At least, the Excel sheet was not modified as it should have been.

Comment: 4. I also can say that, until about July 15, my code did work without any error!!!!

Comment: ==> It seems like some missing library or something strange due to a recent Office update???